# Format ToolTip for TreeNodes in TreeView

Tags: c#, formatting, treeview, tooltip, treenode

I'm currently showing a ToolTip on each of my TreeNodes via

```
myTreeNode.ToolTipText = "My ToolTip";
```

Is there a possibility to format the Text other than creating a ToolTip-Subclass which draws the Text differently?

Comment: I've found a solution in using [HtmlRenderer](http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) which lets you write HTML-Formatted ToolTips which you can use on the TreeView.